# Embed content in facebook feed

Tags: facebook, iframe, embed

How can I share embed content on facebook? For instance this facebook post https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fvine%2Fposts%2F1119625504750685&width=500 links to a Vine item that embeds an iframe. The iframe is from facebook itself, but it runs some javascript from Vine. Can I do that for my own product, or is it some kind of partnership between facebook and Vine?

[image]

I could not find anything about such embedding in fb docs. To clarify, I'm not trying to put facebook content in my website, but my content into facebook.

Comment: You can't. HTML5 embeds are just being tested with a few partners. The only way for you to include interactive content is to use Flash.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

From their website

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

Such as from here:

```
<html>
<title>My Website</title>
<body>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5" 
    async></script>  
<div class="fb-post" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/"
    data-width="500"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to embed facebook content in a website, but how to embed my content into facebook

Comment: IM pretty sure you cant do that

Comment: Sounds like you're right (see the comment from @WizKid)